# Installing Python packages without pip

Tags: python, package

I've been banging my head against the wall all day.    The laptop I use won't allow access to the outside to use pip.   So I went to pypi.org and downloaded the request package.    I've unpacked it into the python/lib folder.

I then go to the command line and navigate to the new folder and run the python setup.py install.

I've never done this before so I was expecting some feedback from the install.

nothing.

I'm using VS as my IDE.

Any thoughts here?

Comment: It seems that you are using an air-gapped computer (or, your computer limits your internet access). In any case, what you need is this: http://chrisclaxton.blogspot.com/2017/05/python-libraries-on-air-gapped-machine.html.

Comment: I tried all of this.   When I go to install, the setup returns with no response.   pip isn't installed either.

Comment: What do you mean by *"won't allow access to outside"*? Do you have internet access from where you are working? A workaround could be to install ubuntu on a portable SSD and then you will have complete access to install whatever you like in that SSD. In fact I work from my Ubuntu system installed on a portable SSD. It uses the other resources of my laptop, but while booting, I choose to log into the ubuntu (completely installed in the SSD ~500GB). This only cost me about $90-$100 to get a as-good-as-new ubuntu laptop!

Comment: I installed miniconda on the *portable-SSD-ubuntu-laptop* and then installing opencv is as simple as `conda install opencv -c conda-forge`. If you want to know more about how to do this, let me know.

Answer (score 4):

I found this as a work around

```
python -m pip install ....
```

Python is an environmental variable.  The laptop I'm working on is a work laptop that I need to return, but since my personal laptop died (no boot device was found was that last information it reported).  I am probably not set up as an administrator on this device.  Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set it up correctly. For whatever package you are installing you need to ***very carefully read the full instructions.*** After you are sure that you have set it up correctly you can check by running a simple python script I found on this question:

[Check if Python Package is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051254/check-if-python-package-is-installed)

You would then just change the module name to the module you tried to install. Hopefully, this helps!

****EDIT*** You might also need to run the command terminal as an administrator depending on how your computer is set up.